# VBA (Powerpoint) - How to add a Chart Object to a slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the following VBA code in powerpoint:

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim sourceWB As Workbook
Dim sourceWS As Worksheet
Dim chartObj As ChartObject

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With xlApp
 .Visible = True
 .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set sourceWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("path\\file.xlsx", , False, , , , , , , True)
Set sourceWS = sourceWB.Worksheets("ChartDump")

Set chartObj = sourceWS.ChartObjects(1)
```

**How do I add `chartObj` to one of my slides?**

There is a chart in the excel document in a worksheet called "ChartDump"

Comment: Have you seen [MSDN documentation?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff973127(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Hi, I was actually following that tutorial and I have been going through the documentation (which lacks examples and detail). That creates a new chart. I want to add an existing one... starting to think it's impossible. Only solution I have seen is with copy and paste which seems unnecessary if I have the chart in memory

Comment: change the `How do I add chartObj to one of my slides?`, because the MSDN website has the example that does that

Comment: Could you link that please?

Comment: are you joking? the link is in the remark posted by @MaciejLos. .... you replied that you followed that tutorial.

Comment: Ah sorry about that. As I said in that comment though it creates a new chart rather than using an existing reference (which in this case is chartObj)